# Setting up daily notifications for a Google Assistant App via DialogFlow

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I apologize if this is a stupid question. I have been spending quite a while trying to get daily updates for my google assistant app to work (found at https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/daily).

I get the prompt on my phone to initiate the daily updates because my server gets the configure updates event. However, I think I am not sending the correct response back because I just get the error "UnparseableJsonResponse: API Version 2: Failed to parse JSON response string with 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' error: ": Cannot find the field."

Usually, my server just responds with a JSON in the structure:

```
return{
        "speech": 'sample text',
        "DisplayText": 'sample text',
        "source": "sample"
    }
```

However, according to the Google documentation, I need to return the JSON

```
{
   "conversationToken":"",
   "expectUserResponse":true,
   "expectedInputs":[
      {
         "inputPrompt":{
            "initialPrompts":[
               {
                  "textToSpeech":"PLACEHOLDER_FOR_REGISTER_UPDATE"
               }
            ],
            "noInputPrompts":[

            ]
         },
         "possibleIntents":[
            {
               "intent":"actions.intent.REGISTER_UPDATE",
               "inputValueData":{
                  "":"",
                  "intent":"tell.tip",
                  "triggerContext":{
                     "timeContext":{
                        "frequency":"DAILY"
                     }
                  },
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I tried returning this exact JSON but as I suspected it's not that simple. I'm not sure how to adapt this format to one that dialogflow expects. Any help would be much appreciated. Note that I'm looking at the response structure at https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment. I also considered the actions on google structure too at https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse. I'm just very confused on how to do this since the guide is mostly suited for people using node js and the SDK.

Comment: Hey, I'm developing the same functionality, but I'm not getting any daily updates, can you please share how to do that! I'm trying but `actions.intent.REGISTER_UPDATE` intent not calling implicitly!

Comment: What versions of Actions on Google and Dialogflow are you using?